# Terraform > Resource > name - invalid or unknown key

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

According to this https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html you can have a `resource` with a `name`. E.g.

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "timeout_example" {
  allocated_storage = 10
  engine            = "mysql"
  engine_version    = "5.6.17"
  instance_class    = "db.t1.micro"
  name              = "mydb"

  # ...

  timeouts {
    create = "60m"
    delete = "2h"
  }
}
```

but my sample `tf` file:

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = "<access key>"
  secret_key = "<secret key>"
  region     = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = "ami-0d729a60"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id = "<subnet-id>"
  name = "web"
}
```

gives me `* aws_instance.web: : invalid or unknown key: name`.

Any idea why?

Comment: I don't see `name` listed among the metaparameters in the doc you linked to.

Comment: As Matt mentions, that's not one of the meta parameters on every resource and is just a parameter for that particular resource. If you want to name an EC2 instance you'll need to set the `Name` tag

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate on the comments above. You're creating an instance of the `aws_db_instance` resource. Checking the documentation [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/db_instance.html) for that resource type, there is no mention of the `name` attribute, so the error seems valid and I guess it's just a bug in the Terraform documentation (not sure where you can report it).

To give your db a "name", you can use the `Name` AWS tag in your resource definition:

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "my-database" {
  ...
  tags {
    "Name" = "My-Database-Name"
  }
}
```

Comment: Report comments to hashicorp at https://www.hashicorp.com/contact/general

Answer (score 1):

This is not working because `name` is not a valid argument of the aws_db_instance resource type. You can find a list of all the valid arguments for this resource [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/db_instance.html#argument-reference).

In the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html) that you linked, this paragraph is found.

> **Description**
>
> The resource block creates a resource of the given TYPE (first parameter) and NAME (second parameter). The combination of the type and name must be unique.

This is referencing the second parameter of the entire resource; so when you have:

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "timeout_example" {
     ...
}
```

The "name" parameter is "timeout_example".